# record system sound directly

Tags: iphone

Instead of playing something out the speaker and recording it through the mic, can I just record the system sound and not use the mic at all? How should I proceed for this? What should I use as framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing uncompressed sounds using the Audio Queue or Audio Unit Remote IO APIs, you can just write to a file the same sound samples which you use to fill the callback buffers, and you will have recorded what you played.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more in details please? I'm quite new to iphone programming and I find the algorithm of audio queue services very complex :s

Comment: My answer might include vocabulary requiring knowledge of Cocoa or posix file IO, C data types, C arrays, audio file formats, and basic DSP concepts.  Once you know all that, you will be able to look at the buffer callback code, and won't need my explanation.

Comment: if you cannot explain anything, better not to say anything just for the fun of talking